# Supabase useSession/useUser returns null at first, which leads to incorrect content rendering

Tags: next.js, supabase

I am trying to conditionally render a login page with Supabase, whereby if the user is already logged in, there should be a redirect to the home page. I am using NextJS 13.

Right now, I have this:

```
import {
    Auth,
    // Import predefined theme
    ThemeSupa,
} from '@supabase/auth-ui-react'
import { useSession, useSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react'
import { Box } from '@mantine/core';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function AuthComp() {
    const supabase = useSupabaseClient()
    const session = useSession()
    const router = useRouter()

    console.log(session)

    if (session) {
        router.push('/')
    } else {
        return (
            <Box sx={{
                paddingLeft: '35vw',
                paddingRight: '35vw',
                paddingTop: '10vh',
            }}>
                <Auth
                    redirectTo="http://localhost:3000"
                    supabaseClient={supabase}
                    theme="dark"
                    appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
                    providers={['google', 'github', 'linkedin']}
                />
            </Box>
        )
    }
}
```

However, it seems that `useSession` may be returning null at first, leading to the Auth-UI rendering for a split second, and then returning the session, leading to the redirect.

[image]
I want to make it so that the Auth-UI rendering for a split second does not happen. Is this possible? The docs are unclear about this.

I have confirmed this happens if I use `useUser` as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `isLoading` flag on the `useSessionContext` hook:

```
const { isLoading, session, error } = useSessionContext();
```

See an example here: https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/blob/main/examples/nextjs/pages/index.tsx#L13

Comment: Thank you I wonder, what's the difference between `useSession` and `useSessionContext`

Comment: @YassineSedrani I did some research, this is what I found, comparing to `useSessionContext`. The `useSession` hook from supabase auth helper, it is an async function, and it does not include the state of whether it is loading or error, which it means it will always be null in the beginning (which it means it is in loading).